# gensim LDA output

Tags: python, nlp, lda

Can someone please explain meaning of each elemnt of the gensim LDA's output?
For exmaple, I have a trained LDA and now I want to get topic distribution for unseen doc.

```
other_texts = [['computer', 'time', 'graph'],
    ['survey', 'response', 'eps'],
    ['human', 'system', 'computer']]




id2word_unseen = corpora.Dictionary(other_texts) # словарь

corpus_word_freq_unseen = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in other_texts]


unseen_doc = corpus_word_freq_unseen[0]
vector = LDA[unseen_doc]  # get topic probability distribution for a document
```

Vector variable consists of

```
([(0, 0.020873228),
  (1, 0.012368388),
  (2, 0.029045772),
  (3, 0.01218763),
  (4, 0.8807166),
  (5, 0.0141737955),
  (6, 0.010576158),
  (7, 0.020058472)],
 [(2118, [4]), (9354, [4])],
 [(2118, [(4, 0.99984014)]), (9354, [(4, 0.9996126)])])
```

First element is distribution, but I don't understand meaning of other elements.
Thank you!